# ClassNotFoundError when I run the class outside of eclipse

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, max-msp-jitter

I currently try to run java code in Maxmsp using a mxj object, and I want to load some classes inside of the code.
But I always get the errors, although the code runs properly in eclipse.

What is the problem?

This is my code.
If I bang in Maxmsp, `call()` will be called.

```
package Load;

import com.cycling74.max.*;

public class Loaded extends MaxObject{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //This works properly in eclipse
        call();
    }

    public void bang() {
        //This should work in Maxmsp, but get errors
        call();
    }

    public static void call() {
        try {
             //this is just a example
             //I want to load some classes which locate the same directory as this class
            Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass("Load.Loaded");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the error message:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Load.Loaded
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at Load.Loaded.call(Loaded.java:21)
    at Load.Loaded.bang(Loaded.java:16)
```

MXJ System class path is:

```
/Applications/Max.app/Contents/Resources/C74/packages/max-mxj/java-classes/lib/commons-codec-1.11.jar:
/Applications/Max.app/Contents/Resources/C74/packages/max-mxj/java-classes/lib/core.jar:
/Applications/Max.app/Contents/Resources/C74/packages/max-mxj/java-classes/lib/gluegen-rt-natives-macosx-universal.jar:
/Applications/Max.app/Contents/Resources/C74/packages/max-mxj/java-classes/lib/gluegen-rt.jar:
/Applications/Max.app/Contents/Resources/C74/packages/max-mxj/java-classes/lib/jitter.jar:
/Applications/Max.app/Contents/Resources/C74/packages/max-mxj/java-classes/lib/jode-1.1.2-pre-embedded.jar: 
/Applications/Max.app/Contents/Resources/C74/packages/max-mxj/java-classes/lib/jogl-all-natives-macosx-universal.jar: 
/Applications/Max.app/Contents/Resources/C74/packages/max-mxj/java-classes/lib/jogl-all.jar: 
/Applications/Max.app/Contents/Resources/C74/packages/max-mxj/java-classes/lib/max.jar: 
/Applications/Max.app/Contents/Resources/C74/packages/max-mxj/java-classes/lib/sadamLib.jar
```

MXJ Classloader CLASSPATH is:

```
/Applications/Max.app/Contents/Resources/C74/packages/max-mxj/java-classes/classes/
/Applications/Max.app/Contents/Resources/C74/packages/max-mxj/java-classes/
/Users/MyName/Documents/ecllipse-workspace/009_Processing/bin
```

Loaded.class is in `/Users/MyName/Documents/ecllipse-workspace/009_Processing/bin`

Comment: Sounds like a classpath error, would you happen to be able to post what your classpath is set to whilst using the workflow that causes the error?

Comment: Which classpath do I have to post? system path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was what Max cannot load class properly.
So I created class loader method.

```
public static ClassLoader createClassLoader(String dirname) throws java.io.IOException {
    java.net.URL[] url = new java.net.URL[1];
    java.io.File file;
    if (dirname.endsWith("/")) {
        file = new java.io.File(dirname);
    }
    else {
        file = new java.io.File(dirname + "/");
    }
    url[0]= file.toURI().toURL();

    ClassLoader parent = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    java.net.URLClassLoader loader = new java.net.URLClassLoader(url, parent);
    return loader
}
```

And call

```
ClassLoader loader = createClassLoader("ClassPath");
Class<?> c = Class.forName("Classname", true, loader);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include any of your dependencies on the classpath:

```
java -cp "path/to/maxmsp.jar;path/to/dependency2.jar;path/to/your.jar" classpath.of.your.Main
```

If you are just running directly from a classfile and haven't JARred your project then you can omit the `path/to/your.jar` and just run from the same directory with the classpath of your Main.

The above is for running java from command line.

---

Since Max is what is running and what's taking control of the classloading im guessing that `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader` is not working. Try debugging and see what it's doing. Also maybe try to find a way to use the Max classloader instead of the Java `AppClassLoader`.

Comment: This solution is useful only in command line, right?
This problem happens running class not from command line but from Maxmsp. MaxMsp is node base programming environmental, so I cannot write dependencies in such a way. Is there any suggestion which I can solve the problem?